# A is B that is C, C refers to A or B?

Tags: american-english

> He works in our company that is nice.

In the above sentence, "nice" refers to company? or it can also refer to company?

How about a general A is B that is C sentence?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but if it were punctuated in some way or other, I count three possible meanings. 1. It is nice that this fellow works in our company. 2. He works in our company; and our company is a nice company. 3. We have a number of companies. One of them is nice, the others are nasty. He works in the nice one.

Comment: Need a period or semicolon to split the sentence in twain for that first one, but it would work. The other two are equally valid as written. Yeah... this is not a clear construction and only context would let you figure out intent. Avoid accordingly. (Unless you want the ambiguity for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> He works in our company that is nice.

"that is nice" is a restrictive relative clause modifying the noun "company", and "our" is a determiner that combines with "company that is nice" to form the complete noun phrase "our company that is nice".  (This analysis isn't altogether obvious -- the alternatives are discussed in McCawley's book **TSPE**.)

The only possible interpretation that I can find is that we have several companies, some of which are not nice and one of which is nice, and that he works in the nice one.  There is just one company being referred to that he works in, since "our" is a definite determiner, and there must be more than one company that we have, because the relative clause is restrictive -- for it to restrict the reference to just one company, there must be several companies meeting the description when the relative clause is not present.

This is a rather odd thing to say, so maybe the relative clause should not have been restrictive, in which case "which" would have been used instead of "that", and a comma would precede the relative clause.

Comment: if you want to write the same sentence in such a way that nice refers to He, how you do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do that using a relative clause.  *"He works in our company who is nice" is not good, because "who is nice" is not next to the definite noun phrase "he".  However, relative clauses don't have to be next to indefinites that they go with, so you could have "A man works in our company who is nice" (though this is not great, stylistically).

Comment: "It is nice that he works in our company." or "There's a nice man who works in our company " (depends on what you want to say).

Comment: "He, who is nice, works at our company." or, if you wanted to state hiring ideals: "He who is nice works at our company."

Comment: @Susan "He works in our company and he is nice".